# How to get QGIS to display grayscale of an SRTM geotiff?

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff

I cannot get QGIS to recognise my SRTM geotiff as having any grayscale elevation data. In the screenshots below, opening the geotiff file in MicroDEM by default hillshades and pseudocolors the hypsometry, so the file definitely holds z-value data.

The screenshot from QGIS further below, where I have opened the same geotiff file and checked the properties histogram, shows that none of this elevation data is apparently recognised by QGIS. I must be doing something wrong, but what?

(SRTM = Shuttle Radar Topography Mission)

My geotiff opened in MicroDEM (good):
[image: Microdem view of my geotiff file]

The same geotiff opened in QGIS (bad):
[image: QGIS view of my geotiff file]

Comment: I can see that your data has very big and very small values... I think that the NoData value (looks like 32768) isn't set properly. Go to your transparency tab and input 32768 (or whatever your white samples as) into the additional nodata then it should scale nicely.

Comment: What Michael said. And also, on the style dialog, play with different options.